# 500 Error With Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to edit my channel description using the Youtube Data API V3, but I get a "500 Internal Server Error" if I try to do anything with "brandingSettings". I even tried starting a private browsing session and using a different Google account. Is this a Google issue that will be fixed soon? Or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Sorry, I am new. I am just using the "Try It!" thing on developers.google.com.

Request:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&key={API_KEY}

{
"brandingSettings": {
"channel": {
"description": "testing"
}
}
}
```

Response:

```
500 Internal Server Error

Cache-Control:  private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding:  gzip
Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:  Tue, 31 May 2016 20:29:18 GMT
Expires:  Tue, 31 May 2016 20:29:18 GMT
Server:  GSE
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Vary:  Origin, X-Origin

{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "backendError",
"message": "Backend Error"
}
],
"code": 500,
"message": "Backend Error"
}
}
```

Comment: Are you going to ask a car mechanic what's wrong with your car if you visited his garage while your car is at home? With other words: where is your code?

Comment: Welp I cant tell you what you are doing wrong since I have no code, but I can can assure you the problem is user error.  Flyoffacliff with 0 repuation vs Google -- Im gonna go with google everytime. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post with more information.

Comment: Looks like someone else just reported this a few weeks ago. Amazing that Google has not fixed such a major issue in weeks! https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8188

Answer (score 1):

If you get a [500 Error](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) wait some minutes and try again. If you still get a 500 Error try and wait some hours or some days. Please make sure that you are giving the right channel id.

The way to do it in API, do a channels->list request and use that response object, modify it and put it back. (Most important make sure the id is there and set.)

***HTTP request***

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
```

Note: This request requires [authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) with at least on of the following scopes.

Use the API Explorer to call this method on live data and see the API request and response: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update#try-it