# Using WebRTC and uploading video to YouTube

Tags: php, youtube-api, webrtc, service-accounts

I'm working on a project where I would like to use WebRTC to record a video from my PHP website and upload it to my YouTube channel.  For the code below I am just trying to get an upload to work, as the video is saved on my server. I'm not clear on what kind of key or authorization I need to use.  After reading and studying the documentation, I think I need to use a service account (key) to accomplish this?
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts

I do not want users to log in/authenticate a google account. I would like the upload to happen from my website to my YouTube channel.

I don't have access to install with composer, so I have uploaded the google-api-php-client (v2.2.2) folder on my server.

I haven't been able to find any current examples that are closer to what I need, so I'm trying to mashup these pieces:

Uploads to Drive: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/media_upload
Uses the Service Account key(?): https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
Upload Video: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video

I'm getting Any guidance is appreciated.  I am receiving a "This page isn't working" HTTP ERROR 500

Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
<?php

    if (!file_exists('google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
    }

    require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

    session_start();

    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=I-Video/i-video-recording-0e9cbc2cad7a.json');
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();


    $file = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
    $result = $service->files->insert($file, array(
    'data' => file_get_contents("data/1530103005236.webm"),
    'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'uploadType' => 'media'
    ));
?>
```

Comment: [Error 500](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) in the documentation means the request failed due to an internal error. Try the solution in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553439/500-error-with-youtube-api), like wait some minutes and try again or wait some hours or some days.

Comment: It looks like maybe I'm trying something impossible with the service key and YouTube?  "The service account flow supports server-to-server interactions that do not access user information. However, the YouTube Data API does not support this flow. Since there is no way to link a Service Account to a YouTube account, attempts to authorize requests with this flow will generate a NoLinkedYouTubeAccount error." - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication